# Solder Wave Residue

Tags: soldering, wave, solder-paste

Issue: 1-3 days after maintenance, chunks of solder residue starts to show in the solder wave bath. This creates blockage in the nozzle. Any notes how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Notes:

- No new chemicals or changes have been made.
- Before the same result was shown after around 20 days.
- Leadfree solder.

Comment: Is the temperature correct?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Yes, all within the datasheet parameters. Moreover, we have had the same setup/parameters for years now. Also, for the first day it's all perfect.

Comment: Yes, the settings, but is it actually at the settings?